# Where are docker images and containers stored when we use it with Windows 8.1?

Tags: docker, windows-8.1, docker-for-windows

I Am  new to Docker and using  Udemy tutorial for learning.

```
$ docker info say its path is /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
```

I can't see this path  on my Windows machine.

Thanks!